# Sub menu hover transition effect in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a top menu bar with a second level dropdown. It works fine in FF but not in Chrome.

In Chrome , on mouse out the background color is getting disappeared first and then the links. So there is a little timing gap of disappearance between color and links.

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="top_menu">
    <ul class="show-for-medium-up">
        <li class="first active"><a href="index.php">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="weddings.php">About Us</a>

        </li>
        <li class="rev has_dropdown"><a href="wedding-services.php">wedding services</a>

            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="first"><a href="#">wedding decor</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">lights &amp; drapping</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">linen</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">catering</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">transport</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last"><a href="contact.php">contact us</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/71f15Lc6/

It works fine in firefox.Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sections:

```
a {
    font-weight: 600;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.top_menu ul li ul li a {
    color:#bcb194;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding:0.5rem 0 0.5rem 0.8rem;
    margin:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

These sections have transitions for the individual `<a>` elements which are playing after your menu closes. Without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish a simple solution would be to remove the transitions from these.

Heres a working Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/71f15Lc6/1/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes you are correct. The <a> transition are effecting on sub menu close.Actually the transition will be on main menu but not on sub menu.

Comment: It's fixed now. The transition on <a> is remained same but removed the effect from top menu ul li ul li a